# Are there any English Bible translations whose primary text for the OT is the Septuagint?

Tags: bible-translation, septuagint

The translators of most English Bible translations used the Hebrew Masoretic Text as their primary source for the Old Testament, though they will use the Septuagint and other texts to critically analyse the Hebrew text. (You can see evidence of this in footnotes that note that the Hebrew says one thing and the Greek says another.)

Are there any English Bible translations of both the OT and the NT whose primary text for the OT is the Septuagint?

Comment: Well there are a few different translations of the Septuagint, and most modern translations would use it in their critical analysis of the Hebrew text. But translations of the Old and New Testaments which use only the Septuagint for the OT would be pretty strange and unusual...

Comment: Also, isn't the Dhouay-Rheims a translation from the Vulgate?!?

Answer (score 15):

There are a few. Some of them are published as academic works, while others are intended for the common use and worship (especially in Eastern Orthodox Churches).

The first was [*The Holy Bible containing the Old and New Covenant*](https://archive.org/details/holybiblecontain03thom), translated by Charles Thomson in 1808 (though he did not include the apocrypha). It can still be bought [today](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1147578508). The translation was revised and enlarged by C. A. Muses in 1954 as [*The Septuagint Bible*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RDNNP4).

Sir Lancelot Brenton published [one](http://www.ecmarsh.com/lxx/) in 1851. It has continually been in print since then and was updated as [*LXX2012: Septuagint in English 2012*](http://ebible.org/eng-lxx2012/).

There is also the [New English Translation of the Septuagint](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/) (NETS). Even here, they have to do textual criticism as the extant copies of the LXX don't all agree. In the translation [principles](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/principles.html), the committee states they have a target audience "that closely approximates that of the NRSV."

The [Eastern Orthodox churches](http://orthodoxwiki.org/Septuagint#Different_Translations_of_the_Septuagint_in_English) in English-speaking countries also have several options available for English translations based off the Septuagint. In 2008, [*The Orthodox Study Bible*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0718003594) was released. It uses the [semi-critical *Septuaginta*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598561804) of Alfred Rahlfs as its base. Peter King, SJ, has also released a translation of the Septuagint in four volumes: *The Pentateuch* 2010, *The Historical Books* 2012, *The Wisdom Literature* 2008, and *The Prophets* 2013.

Comment: [An article](https://williamaross.com/2014/11/24/lxx-translations-part-i-nets/) on the translation philosophy of the NETS.
[Another site](https://www.ccel.org/bible/brenton/) for the Brenton translation, [and another](https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/default.asp) providing also the Greek text side-by-side.

Comment: A new user (not yet able to comment) was interested in your answer and sought to clarify some issues arising from it. They have posted those queries [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61248/is-the-ot-translation-in-the-apostolic-bible-polyglot-based-strictly-on-the) should you be willing to address them.