# Is there an English translation of the OT, which is strictly based on the Septuagint?

Tags: bible-translation, septuagint

The Masoretic Text was used as the basis for translations of the Old Testament in Protestant Bibles, such as the King James Version (KJV), and American Standard Version, and for some versions of Catholic Bibles (after 1943). However, the text is sometimes adjusted to conform to the Greek LXX in passages where clarification or Christological interpretation was felt necessary.

But is there any English translation, which **only** uses the Septuagint (LXX)?

Comment: This question was already asked in answered here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34178/are-there-any-english-bible-translations-whose-primary-text-for-the-ot-is-the-se?rq=1

Comment: You can see what edits were performed by clicking on the [edit history](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/61243/revisions) accessible via the "edited XXXX ago" link at the bottom of your question. Re the answer, the poster self-deleted after he realised this was a duplicate question - perhaps he'll post his answer there, or he has judged that all of the relevant content exists in the answer that is already there.

Comment: No problem.  It's entirely legitimate to use comments to learn/teach about site functions. Mods can delete them later when they have outlived their usefulness.